# Storing large analytical data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to store large analytical data in MySQL. I'm no MySQL guru, so I'm looking for advice on the optimal way to proceed.

This data will continue to grow over time so I understand that storing it in a single cell, even if split amongst several rows is a really bad idea.

So what would be the optimal way to do this? Would I need to generate a new row after a certain length in the cell is reached? Or am I looking at this completely wrong?

Please bear in mind that I am using Wordpress.

Comment: Have a look at database normalisation, that should help you. For everything else, we need more context - for example, why is this connected to Wordpress?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you, I will look into that. I have a Wordpress site that will be recording specific data in relation to users actions. This data will be represented to the users in the form of a graph.